# Forbidden: You don't have permission to access sompathm/a.jpg on this server

Tags: macos, apache, webserver, httpd.conf

I have hosted a php page in my local apache web server in mac.
I am not able to show images.
I am getting the above problem.
I couldn't solve the problem.

I am using el-capitan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click the *image file*
2. choose get info Go to *Sharing & Permissions*
3. In the *privilege* choose *ReadOnly* for the *Name everyone*